# How to share mobile browser url to whatsapp on button click using jquery?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to share my mobile browser url through whatsapp using custom button...is it possible?
Like that (When i click on button , mobile whatsapp open if it is there otherwise it will display "WhatsApp not Installed")

Comment: As it stands, this question is too broad and a little unclear. Stack Overflow is for solving specific programming problems, not general help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

#### iOS

In iOS you can use a [URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) for that.
In a nutshell, URL schemes are special URLs that are registered by native applications so that any other application navigating to that URL is forwarding their request to the native app associated with that URL scheme.

Check out [this link](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/iphone/23559013) on the whatsapp website which explains how to use the URL scheme.

#### Android

In Android you deal with this in a different way. Android uses [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and [Activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).
You can check out [this](http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=96250) to a similar question.

Comment: Ok,but how to add this code in my asp.net mvc application or using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=[TITLE] : [Link]?utm_source=site%26utm_medium=social_share%26utm_content=whatsapp" data-action="[Link]"></a>
```

This will work